# Automatic downvote spree detection

Tags: support, down-votes

Is there an automatic downvote spree detection on SuperUser? I just got a notification that I've gotten downvotes on my answers and quite interestingly they're all at the same time period and for different questions. I assume it's a single person trying to make me feel bad, for whatever reason.

> -2     12 hours ago    downvote    Switching boot disk, have mirrored drives
>   -2  12 hours ago    downvote    Why did Windows 8.1 damage the security permissions on a drive from another Windows installation
>   -2  12 hours ago    downvote    Computer stuck someone between QWERTY and Dvorak
>   -2  12 hours ago    downvote    Can a TV decode audio passed to it from a HDMI port?
>   -2  12 hours ago    downvote    What purpose does a modem serve?
>   -2  12 hours ago    downvote    Are subnets always contiguous 1s?

There is also one question on SO downvoted at the same time.

Also the interesting thing is that I've been on SU and SO today several times, but only now suddenly these show and it says they happened already 12h ago. Is there some kind of a delay for showing them?

Comment: heh, there's something going on here. It *ought* to be rolled back within 24 hours. Else, let me know and I'll get a CM to do what's needed.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek At least four out of the six were already reverted, have to see if the two others also will. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is, and it's documented in the Help Centre.

https://superuser.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

> When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your
> posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes
> to be invalid and removes them.
>
> Such votes will generally be invalidated as part of an automated
> process that runs every day, but may also be invalidated manually by
> the staff after an investigation. When the votes are invalidated, the
> reputation gain or loss from the votes is undone, which results in a
> record in the recipient's reputation history labelled "voting
> corrected".
>
> **What if I think I'm the victim of voting abuse?**
>
> If you see very unusual votes being targeted at your account, don't worry about it. You should wait at least 24 hours after noticing before becoming concerned, as the automated system should detect it and reverse it for you. If, after 24 hours, you do not see any fix to your reputation, please contact the team using the "contact us" form located at the bottom of any page.

Comment: Thanks, was looking with wrong keywords so didn't find this one.

Comment: Does this work across sites on the network? How "many" are "many posts"? I have encountered the same problem right now and a user revenge-downvoted after I explained that his answer was not very precise.